# Is it possible to make HTML element attributes immutable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, immutability

If I want to make a javascript object's properties immutable, I can use Object methods such as `defineProperties()`, `defineProperty()`, and `freeze()`. My question is, how can I do the same with HTML element attributes?

I've already tried the aforementioned methods, and while they can be used to prevent an element's properties from being set directly (e.g. `elem.id = 'foo';`), as expected, the underlying attributes can still be changed via `setAttribute()`.

An answer of "no, it's not possible" would be acceptable, but I haven't come across any definitive statement to that effect yet.

Comment: till now it is not supported in javascript but may from ECMAScript 5  JavaScript library could support immutable properties.

Comment: You could redefine `setAttribute()` on that element to just throw an error. That might work, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: You could still use `otherElement.setAttribute.call(thatElement, ...)` If someone is determined enough... :p However, it would protect against simple mistakes, even if it's ineffective against malicious users. Depends what OP needs, really.

Comment: I was mainly just trying to decrease the likelihood that some blundering newbie programmer who is oblivious to my meticulously-planned attribute manipulations could stumble in and ruin everything :) iamnotmaynard's idea would probably be conducive to that goal.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard `document.body.attributes.class.value += " foo"` Bam! I've changed an attribute [without using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.attributes) `setAttribute()`.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo You should really edit your question to specify your goal. You mention in your comment wanting to prevent blunders. That's a much lower bar than saying "make it **completely** impossible to ever change this attribute once it is set".

Comment: @Louis, I thought about narrowing the scope to cover my specific circumstance, but I really think the broader question needs an answer. There are probably lots of reasons a programmer would want to freeze an element's attributes, and it either is possible, or it isn't. If it isn't, then of course I'd just have to settle for the next best thing, whatever that may be.

Comment: Maybe you should simply properly document your "*meticulously-planned attribute manipulations*" and make sure any fellow newbie programmer reads and understands them.

Comment: @Bergi Documentation is great, but I'm not sure it's a good substitute for making your code harder to break. You wouldn't skip form validation just because your site has an FAQ, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use mutation observers to restore the old attribute value.

```
new MutationObserver(callback)
    .observe(elem, {attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true});

function callback(mutations, observer) {
    var target = mutations[0].target;
    observer.disconnect();
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        target.setAttribute(mutation.attributeName, mutation.oldValue);
    });
    observer.observe(target, {attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true});
}
```

Thanks to @DoctorDestructo for the suggestions involving `observer.disconnect` which are necessary to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: That looks like an infinite loop, but I like the idea.

Comment: I have no experience with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but it does look promising. In the absence of a "set-it-and-forget-it" solution like defineProperty(), this might be the best option.

Comment: I tested a variation of this and found that it doesn't revert attribute values while a script is running, only afterward. So it really doesn't even create the illusion of immutability. I'm not sure that eliminates it as a viable alternative, though. Another thing to be aware of is that MutationObserver isn't supported in IE < 11.

Comment: In case my previous comment suggested otherwise, I should point out that this code won't work at all as-is. The infinite loop needs to be fixed, and the `observe()` method needs an additional parameter: `attributeOldValue: true`. **[Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/py19g2xs/)** if you want to see my suggested edit. It has been tested, and it works (as well as this technique can).

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Thanks for your fixes. I've incorporated them into the answer.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for your answer; it definitely taught me something new. Even if it's not true immutability, I'm inclined to accept it as a workaround. Just one final suggestion: replace `discounnect()` with `disconnect()` :)

Comment: Was looking for this. Thanks for elegant solution!